# browser side javascript markdown fit for server side upskirt

Tags: javascript, markdown

https://github.com/tanoku/upskirt

> Upskirt has optional support for
>   several (unofficial) Markdown
>   extensions, such as non-strict
>   emphasis, fenced code blocks, tables,
>   autolinks, strikethrough and more.

Upskirt for server side looks very good. but my website need a preview like what stackoverflow does,  so I wish there is a javascript library good enough support the extensions that upskirt support especially fenced code blocks.

Comment: The link to upskirt gives a 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript implementation of upskirt: http://github.com/tanoku/jsupskirt